# Qt connect пытается искать слот в QObject

Tags: qt

Доброго времени суток. Сделал простенький класс таймера в Qt

timer.h:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include <udp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class TimerUdp: public QObject
{
  public:
    TimerUdp(Udp *udp_p);
     ~TimerUdp();

   private:
     QTimer *timer;
     Udp *udp;

   private slots:
     void slot_timer();

};
```

timer.cpp:

```
#include "timer.h"


TimerUdp::TimerUdp(Udp *udp_p)
{
   udp = udp_p;
   timer = new QTimer(this);
   connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(slot_timer()));
   timer->start(1000);
}


TimerUdp::~TimerUdp()
{
  delete timer;
  delete udp;
}


void TimerUdp::slot_timer()
{
   printf("tttt\n"); 

}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "udp.h"
#include "timer.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  Udp *udp = new Udp();

  udp->SetParams("172.17.172.133", 1234, 1235);

  TimerUdp *timer = new TimerUdp(udp);

  return a.exec();
}
```

После запуска таймер не работает и выдается предупреждение:

QObject::connect: No such slot QObject::slot_timer()

Почему connect пытается найти слот в классе QObject, а не в классе TimerUdp?
Как сделать правильно, чтобы он искал слот именно в TimerUdp?

Comment: Потому что у вас нет строки `Q_OBJECT` в объявлении класса `TimerUdp`. Из-за этого Qt его не видит.

Comment: Я добавил Q_OBJECT: class TimerUdp: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    TimerUdp(Udp *udp_p);
    ~TimerUdp();

  private:
    QTimer *timer;
    Udp *udp;

  private slots:
    void slot_timer();

};  Теперь пять раз вылазит ошибка undefined reference to 'vtable for timerUdp'

Comment: Закройте среду разработки, удалите папку, куда производится сборка, затем заново соберите проект. А Q_OBJECT нужен для того, чтобы специальная Qt-шная утилита, натравливаемая системой сборки на все  заголовочные файлы, знала, что для этого класса надо сгенерировать дополнительный код с описанием сигналов и слотов. Без этого кода слот не будет доступен по строковому имени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил макрос Q_OBJECT  в timer.h:

```
class TimerUdp: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    TimerUdp(Udp *udp_p);
    ~TimerUdp();

  private:
    QTimer *timer;
    Udp *udp;

 private slots:
    void slot_timer();
};
```

Как посоветовали в комментарии выше закрыл qt, удалил сборку, пересобрал. Теперь все работает.